# QField Coordinate Reference System

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, accuracy, qfield, mobile-gis

Does anyone know how location services on your mobile device compare to a chosen coordinate system set in the QGIS project?  I am wondering how to improve the accuracy of my device compared to the layers I am navigating to in QField, is there a way to determine the location services CRS?

Comment: I think the answer would depend on what kind of device you're using. You should look for this information in the documentation for your mobile device.

Comment: GPS always returns latitudes and longitudes in WGS84. Presumably QGIS is passing along the transformation from your project to QField.  Setting your QGIS project to WGS84 will avoid any transformation error leaving you with whatever error you are getting from your mobile device.

Comment: Great thank you so much, I'm going to transform and look at the difference.